# How to inspect CSV file columns inside RSpec test?

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I really don't know how to inspect CSV file I created in my ROR App.

```
require "rails_helper"
require "shared_contexts/vcr/s3"
require "csv"

RSpec.describe ReportRuns::RunService do
  describe "CSV columns" do
    include_context "vcr s3 put csv"

    let(:report_run) { create :report_run, report_template: report_template, created_by: user.id, mime_type: "csv" }
    #let(:report_template) { create :report_template, template_structure: { module: "trial_members", filters: { trial_members: [trial_members.id] } } }
    let(:report_template) { create :report_template, trial: trial }
    let(:trial) { create :trial }
    let(:user) { create :user }
    let(:user_role) { create :user_role }

    subject { described_class.new(report_run) }

    before do
    end

    it do
      get :index, format: :csv
      p "response jee: #{response.body}"
      p response.headers
      p "report run: #{report_run.inspect}"
      p "templejt: #{report_template.inspect}"
      p "mime type: #{report_run[:mime_type]}"
      #p "trila je: #{trial.inspect}"
      p "users are: #{user.inspect}"
      p "user roles su: #{user_role.inspect}"
      is_expected.to be_truthy
      expect(5).to match(5)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`CSV` library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to parse the body of the response. Then work with the CSV object.

```
csv = CSV.new(response.body)
```

You can also check the Content-type headers are correct, `text/csv`.

Comment: Yes, but from where to get response in this code? Because mine response.body not working, i just tried, but it's not working, neither get method.

Comment: @VladanPetrovic You should mention that you're having trouble getting the response body in your question. `response` should work so long as RSpec realizes this is a Controller test. Try setting `RSpec.describe ReportRuns::RunService, type: :controller`. See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-8/docs/controller-specs for more.